# react google charts - Line chart styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-visualization, react-google-charts

I'm trying to increase the line thickness of my Line Chart implemented using react-google-charts. I have went through the documentation but anything related to line thickness did not work. How do i increase the line thickness and give separate colours to the lines. The below is my implementation and approach to increase the line thickness

```
            <Chart
              width={"98%"}
              height={"290px"}
              chartType="Line"
              loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
              data={transformedArray}
              options={{
                lineWidth: 10,
                colors: ["black", "blue", "red", "green", "yellow", "gray"],
                legend: { position: "none" }
              }}
              rootProps={{ "data-testid": "3" }}
            />
```

`lineWidth: 10` did nothing to the lines.

Comment: Any online demo? Cause the `lineWidth` should work based on their document

Comment: I tried this https://codesandbox.io/s/rakannimerreact-google-charts-linechart-no1t7 and it is working too for me. Can you create sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

In `chartType="Line"` - `lineWidth` doesn't work for me as well. But, `chartType="LineChart"` accepts `lineWidth` as opion key.

You can play with `curveType` (line, function) in option config and try to get desired result.

#### update:

To control colors, use `colors` property (value is array of colors - as much as you have lines):

```
colors: ['yellow', 'green']
```

Comment: [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/rakannimerreact-google-charts-linechart-4rwef)

Comment: I used the exact code of your's but still my lineWidth does not change. But i see in the codesandbox example it's working perfectly. I cannot figure out the issue

Comment: Have you changed `chartType="Line"` to `chartType="LineChart"`? I could help you with debugging but will need to see your code example on codesandbox or codepen.

Comment: Maybe you use some different version of the lib, who knows. Any errors in console?